# Illegal string offset 'Title' while saving api data to db laravel

Tags: laravel, api, guzzle

Am trying to save data from an api to my database 
i have a function to fetch

```
public function index()
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $uri = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=tree&apikey=';
        $header = ['headers' => ['X-Auth-Token' => 'My-Token']];
        $res = $client->get($uri, $header);
        $data = json_decode($res->getBody()->getContents(), true);
  return $data;
    }
```

And then a function to save in my db

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $movies = $this->index();
//        dd($this->index());

        collect($movies);
//        dd($movies);

             foreach($movies as $movie) {
//                dd($movie);
                Movie::create([
                    'title' => $movie['Title'],
                     'year' =>$movie['Year'],
                    'type' =>$movie['Type'],
                    'cover_photo' => $movie['Poster'],
                ]);

            }

    }
```

When trying to save i get the error above

Comment: Could you plz add what you get when you dd($this->index()); ?

Comment: can you show us the json format data? for dd($this->index());